# How can I export just the structure of a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, export

I use Ubuntu 14.10 and PhpMyAdmin.

I have a 'big' MySQL database, the size is 900MB. I need just the structure of this database, to use it on my local machine. How can I export the structure only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you specifically asked about phpMyAdmin and the previous answers, while correct, are both about doing this on the command line:

Navigate to the database you wish to export. Across the top row of tabs click "Export"

[image: phpMyAdmin export tab]

Next, click the Custom radio button

[image: Custom export type radio button]

Halfway down the "Format-specific options" area, select "structure" (the default is "structure and data")
[image: Structure/Data/Structure and Data export types]

Check the other options and press Go to download your .sql file with no data, only the table structure.

Answer (score 3):

Dump the table structure only using the command below:

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -uYourUsername -pYourPassword databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your database or table.

Select the Export tab.

Below *Export method*, select Custom.

Below *Tables*, check the appropriate *Structure* boxes.

[image: phpMyAdmin - Export - Custom - Structure]

Comment: Is this a different version of PhpMyAdmin than the one in the [accepted answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86171/6219)?

Comment: Yes @dezso, this is the current version of PHPMyadmin, 4.5.5.1, released 2016-02-29. The accepted answer (Dec 15 '14 at 5:22) is 1 year and 3 months old, for versions 4.3.2 and prior.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump --no-data big_db_name > big_db_name.structure.sql
```

Comment: This is different question, but I think this manual would help http://www.top5freeware.com/pscp-examples

Comment: How is this different from the [other similar answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86108/6219)?